# an array of string to sentences dataframe pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

my dataframe look like

```
Phrase                                           Sentiment
[seri, escapad, demonstr, adag, good, goos]         1
[seri, escapad, demonstr, adag, good, goos]         2
```

when i use the command `df.dtypes`

```
Phrase       object
Sentiment     int64
dtype: object
```

i need to get a dataframe like:

```
Phrase                                           Sentiment
seri escapad demonstr adag good goos            1
seri escapad demonstr adag good bad             2
```

i tried this code

```
df['Phrase'] = df[df.Phrase.map(lambda x: ','.join(x))]
```

what should id do

Comment: Hello, you can convert the list into a String... But.. what do you want to do with the DF?

Comment: @Ika8 sentiment analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost right – you have one extra layer of `df[`. Try this:

```
df['Phrase'] = df.Phrase.map(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

You were already returning the column you want to use to replace `Phrase`, but then you were trying to index by its values, which was producing an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're very close. The following line should do the trick:

```
df['Phrase'] = df['Phrase'].map(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ', ' instead of ','

You can do it without lambda like this:

```
df['Phrase'] = df.Phrase.apply(', '.join)
```

Using lambda:

```
df['Phrase'] = df.Phrase.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```